# Rails 4.2.1 on ubuntu 15.04 execution error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rbenv, ruby-2.2, rails-4-2-1

I've just installed rails 4.2.1 and ruby 2.2.2. When I run `rails new blog`, I get the following error

```
rbenv: rails: command not found

The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.1.6
```

I'm new to linux and it'll help if anyone can tell me where it went wrong

Answer (score 0):

`rbenv` is short for Ruby Environment, and its saying that you seem to have another version of ruby installed - 2.1.6 and that it has the `rails` command.

try installing rails independently using `gem install rails` - I'm assuming you used bundler?

This discussion might give you some ideas from the [rbenv github issue #73](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/issues/73)